# Screwed git repo: Git Extensions stopped showing file versions, Visual Studio Git shows them

Tags: git

I fiddled around with branch and branch deletion and now Git Extensions does not show the history of files.

The Microsoft Git provider inside Visual Studio however shows the history of those files.

So I guess I screwed my repo a little bit. What could be the problem?

Comment: Were these files introduced on that specific branch?

Comment: no, quasi all of the hundreds files, some not touched for a year, have no history anymore (in git extensions).

Comment: If you use msysgit, can you see the history?  I legitimately doubt that this is a bug with Git but rather Git Extensions.

Comment: @Makoto, thx for your input, finally created a fresh repo. history was shown as long as the working dir was empty - really strange. at least there were serious issues because a changed casing of folders - git however is case sensitive, at least git extensions, which causes totally weird parallel folders inside git. so will never ever do that again, lesson learned.